# MVP Correct solution to download big file

Tags: android, mvp

I use MVP. 
Suppose I want to download big file (size abount 20 MB).

Here options:

1. Download file in Presenter
2. Download file in Model
3. Download file in Service
4. Something else

What is the best solution?

P.S. Activity can destroy any time. E.g. when rotate screen.

Comment: standard DownloadManager should be best choice, If you want to keep it in background - Download file in IntentService / JobScheduler

Comment: in model or presenter there is no guarantee that your activity will survive against this download.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you download the file in a repository, which is called from an Use Case (model).

The Use Case should be called asynchronously from the presenter and the result will be returned through a callback and update the view if this view has not been destroyed.

But all the data should be loaded on a repository (api calls, data from files, gps location data, etc). This way your model and presenter don't depend on how or where the data is loaded and should not be changed if the origin of the data changes.

If you decide using the DownloadManager, which is probably the best solution, I think the code should be outside the presenter, model and repository because they should be platform-agnostic and not have android code. This way it's easier to perform unit tests on this files.

Comment: If I use Model for download file.. but if actiivity is destroy (e.g. rotate screen).  Is Model survive the Activity re-creation?

Comment: Yes, the way I do it, with dagger, model and presenter are not destroyed if a user performs screen rotation or the activity/fragment is paused. I suppose all the mvp sample codes you can find will also work this way.

Comment: And if the view is destroyed the presenter receives the event but doesn't cancel the repository action, unless you call the use case to cancel the repository call in case that is what you want to do.

Comment: By the way, for the orientation changes I always have at least one fragment per activity  and follow this guide: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Comment: Yes, actually is probably the best solution. But in that case the code should be outside the presenter, model and repository because this parts should be platform-agnostic and not have android code. This way it's easier to perform unit tests on this files.